# Remove values based on column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data.frame. I would like to make 2 transformations.

Input :

```
 id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t6 t8 t9
  1  s  s  s  w  r  r  t  t  w  s
  2  s  s  s  o  o  w  t  t  o  s
  3  s  s  s  o  w  w  t  t  o  s
  4  s  s  s  o  o  w  t  t  o  s
  5  s  s  s  s  s  s  w  w  s  s
  6  s  s  s  w  t  t  w  w  w  s
```

The first one I would like to delete value after that appear after the 'first w':

Output:

```
 id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7   
  1  s  s  s  w  
  2  s  s  s  o  o  w  
  3  s  s  s  o  w  
  4  s  s  s  o  o  w  
  5  s  s  s  s  s  s  w  
  6  s  s  s  w  t  t  w
```

I would like to save this data frame.

In the second step I would like to save the deleted parts into a new data frame.

```
id  t5 t6 t7 t6 t8 t9
  1  r  r  t  t  w  s
  2     w  t  t  o  s
  3     w  t  t  o  s
  4     w  t  t  o  s
  5           w  s  s
  6           w  w  s
```

Sample data

```
df1<-structure(list(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), t1=c("s","s","s","s","s","s"), t2=c("s","s","s","s","s","s"),t3 = c("s","s","s","s","s","s"),
                    t4 = c("w","o","o","o","s","w"), t5 = c("r","o","w","o","s","t"), t6 = c("r","w","w","w","s","t"),
                    t7 = c("t","t","t","t","w","w"),t6 = c("t","t","t","t","w","w"), t8 = c("w","o","o","o","s","w"), t9=c("s","s","s","s","s","s")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

df1
```

Any help is welcomed

Comment: @akrun Many thanks it works perfectly. What I added to the code was df2<-df2[rowSums(df2 == "w")!=0,, , drop = FALSE], this was not in my example but in my data I have columns without the w. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop option with `apply` would be to loop over the rows (`MARGIN = 1`), find the location of the first 'w' (`match`), `replace` the elements after that location to blank (`""`)

```
df2 <- df1
df2[-1] <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) 
         replace(x, seq_along(x) > match('w', x), '')))
```

The second case would be to change the condition from `>` to `<=` in `replace`

```
df3 <- df1
df3[-1] <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) 
          replace(x, seq_along(x) <= match('w', x), '')))
```

and select only columns that have at least one non-blank element

```
df3 <- df3[c(TRUE, colSums(df3[-1] != '') > 0)]
```